# Regarding popping of vector elements

Tags: c++, binary-tree

The following code is used to find all the root-to-leaf paths which equal a particular `sum`, given a binary tree and a `sum`.

```
class Solution {
public:
    void buildResult(std::vector< std::vector< int > >& result, std::vector< int >& ans, TreeNode* root, int sum) {
        if(!root)
            return;

        ans.push_back(root->val);
        if(root->val==sum && !root->left && !root->right)
            result.push_back(ans);
        buildResult(result, ans, root->left, sum-(root->val));
        buildResult(result, ans, root->right, sum-(root->val));
        ans.pop_back();
    }

    vector<vector<int>> pathSum(TreeNode* root, int sum) {
        std::vector< vector< int > > result;
        std::vector< int > ans;

        if(!root)
            return result;

        buildResult(result, ans, root, sum);
        return result;
    }
};
```

The above code works and generates the expected output.  However, I do not understand the use of the statement `ans.pop_back();` - I understand it is for backtracking, but when exactly is this backtracking carried out?  The values are being inserted into the vector `ans` even before checking if they lie on a valid path.  Besides, the number of `pop_back()`s should be many depending upon how many numbers leading to an incorrect sum have been inserted.  Could someone please explain this working to me?

Thanks!

Comment: You can make a small test case and use a debugger or pencil and paper to see how it works yourself.

Comment: @JamesRoot, I tried that; but I am unable to understand.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backtracking gets carried out by the virtue of the recursive function returning.

The recursive function is recording its path, as it traverses the tree, by pushing the current node into `ans`. When it reaches the leaf it checks the leaf's value, and if it matches it records the path that it just built, by pushing `ans` into `result`.

You can think of `ans` as a bread-crumb trail to the current node. Each time the recursive function enters a node in the tree, it pushes the current node's value into `ans`, and when the right leaf is reached, the tail of breadcrumbs is the path to the leaf node.

Consequently, the recursive function leaves the current node it's visiting by returning. By returning from the recursive call, the recursive function returns to its parent. But not before removing the very last breadcrumb from the current tail of breadcrumbs, restoring the trail of breadcrumbs to contain just the path to its parent, which is precisely where it is returning to.

Comment: Okay, so I got your point to some extent.  Suppose the incorrect order of nodes is `0->2->5->6` and the `sum` is `3`.  So, this path of nodes does not lead to the correct `sum`.  But, since we are working recursively, we have to backtrack and remove not just the last element - even the ones before that (i.e., `6` and `5`, both).  How is this ensured?

Comment: The recursive call will return one level of the tree at a time. Remember when you get to the last node, node 6, you're in the middle of four recursive calls. As each recursive call returns, it removes the last breadcrumb from `ans`. See how simple this is?

Comment: Yes, it is.  My bad, I over-complicated it.  Thank you! :)